# Log in with PayPal: Closing the login window to return to main site

Tags: paypal

I have successfully integrated PayPal Identify/Login but the issue is, the site (my return URL) opens up in the PayPal popup dialogue where the client logged in.

I want the login window to close and then have the main calling window go to the return URL, so the user continues on the main screen.

I can't find any details on how to do this on the PayPal Developer Docs.  Is there an option in the button render that I am missing?

Current code:

```
paypal.use( ['login'], function (login) {
    login.render ({
        "appid":"My_API_ID",
        "authend":"sandbox",
        "scopes":"openid profile email address",
        "containerid":"paypalLogin",
        "responseType":"code",
        "locale":"en-us",
        "buttonType":"LWP",
        "buttonShape":"pill",
        "buttonSize":"lg",
        "fullPage":"false",
        "returnurl":"http://mysite/php/paypal/paypal_api_login.php"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The redirect back happens in the window. Add JS code there to save the URL info or redirect the opening window (set `window.opener.location.href`) and `window.close()` if desired.

Not tested but should be as simple as:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
if(window.opener) { 
  window.opener.location.href = window.location.href;
  window.close()
}
</script>
```

or maybe better to also add and check for an additional parameter

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
const REDIRECT_PARAM = '&redirected_opener=true';
if(window.opener && !window.location.href.includes(REDIRECT_PARAM)) { 
  window.opener.location.href = window.location.href + REDIRECT_PARAM;
  window.close()
}
</script>
```

Comment: Brilliant....all sorted...thank you very much :-)

Comment: I am using the second Javascript and it works. It would be helpful if you could also explain it. How does this work?