# PayPal login button: close popup after login and reload / redirect parent window

Tags: paypal

**What I want to do**
Implement PayPal login button to use customer information from PayPal (name, adress...). After login (or cancel) login popup should be closed and parent window should be reloaded / redirected.

**Current progress**
PayPal button works as expected, user informations can be requested.

**Current problem**
Login popup does not close after login; redirect is done in popup window.

**What I tried**
The only solution for this problem I found is to add JS code in redirect-page on popup to close popup and reload parent window, see eg. [Log in with PayPal: Closing the login window to return to main site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883124/log-in-with-paypal-closing-the-login-window-to-return-to-main-site/76975866#76975866)

All solutions are mostly identical; solution should be something like this in the page called after successful login (redirect url):

```
window.opener.location.href = window.location.href;
window.close()
```

I tried with Firefox, Chrome and Edge; all browser do close popup, but no action in parent window is done because window.opener is null; also window.parent.opener or top.window.opener. Some threads say this is because of security reasons and popup windows with different url than parent window could not access parent window. Is that correct or is there some other way to close PayPal popup? There are many pages that use PayPal login and work as expected, so there must be a solution. Maybe I did something wrong when implementing in my script?

Answer (score 0):

> Some threads say this is because of security reasons and popup windows with different url than parent window could not access parent window.

Do not have it be different.

After login completes, its return within the popup should be to the same domain (and protocol+port) as the opener/parent window.

Comment: Yes, but opener is still null. Popup called in www.mydomain.com/login; after login, popup redirects to www.mydomain.com/paypal and window.opener is null. Is it null because of first url called in Popup is PayPal url?

Comment: use www.mydomain.com/login

Comment: Same behaviour unfortunately...

Comment: Try a different domain/localhost for the top opener window and review your HTTP headers and HTML META equivalents

Comment: Plain script works as expected. Same code in my project does not. But I think I got it: I'm using mod_rewrite for seo; maybe this is the reason for this problem. mydomain.com/login is rewritten to index.php?option=login so I have to find out how to get it working in this environment...

Comment: Preston PHX: I could not get a solution for this. Maybe you can help me? In my example script it works fine (with all url params as in Joomla), but if I put same code in Joomla it does not. In Joomla I disabled seo and mod_rewrite and use non-seo paths like option=com_mycomponent&view=login. I use a component template and output html code is same as in my example - also in paypal popup. But popup keeps open... Any ideas?

Comment: Got it. CSP was the key... Thanks Preston for your help!